# Python Subprocess not Running on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python script that handles running my unit tests for Eclipse:

1. Imports projects to a workspace
2. Builds the project
3. Runs the Executable

[Here is a Gist of my Python script](https://gist.github.com/lucasbrendel/8075d94dcea3c8a05e13)

The cibuild_tests.bat referenced in the script does this:

```
set eclipse_dir=%1
set workspace_dir=%2
set project_dir=%3
set name=%4
set config=%5

%eclipse_dir% -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data %workspace_dir% -import %project_dir% -cleanBuild "%name%/%config%"
```

This all runs perfectly fine, the problem is when `subprocess.call(ex)` is called in `run_executable(...)`. The output from that executable is never displayed in the console. The output is displayed when the batch script is run for building the project from Eclipse. The executable is a Google Test build and i have it set to output an XML file of the results. I can find no record of the file being created anywhere leading me to believe it is never being run.

But my check to see if the executable exists do find the executable so it is present.

Everything runs just as i expect on my local machine.

Question: What prevents the second subprocess call from outputting to the console, or running, in Jenkins but the first one has no issues?

Comment: Do the two files live in the save directory?  Is the CWD for Jenkins that directory, or is it calling it from another location?

Comment: The CWD is the location of the python script. Which is where the batch script is located. The exe files are in a different directory, but within the Jenkins Project Workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i remoted in to the computer and found the issue. It seems a window was popping up reporting a missing DLL for my run process. Once i ensured the DLL was available the error went away and everything built.